# .query() for negated str.contains()?

Tags: python, pandas, contains

I want to filter out every row where a column has a specific string.

If I want to filter every row that contains that string:

```
df.query("column_name.str.contains('stringtosearch')")
```

But if I want to use `.query()` to filter out every row containing that string I need to negate that `str.contains()`.

I do not want to use `df[~d["column_name"].str.contains("stringtosearch")]` because I want a unified syntax and I use `.query()` everywhere else in my code.

How can I do this with `.query()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply with the `~` operator (or `not`) , as demonstrated in the [query docs in indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-operators).

```
df.query("~column_name.str.contains('stringtosearch')")
```